# iterate over items in frame using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer with C#

Tags: c#

How can I iterate over the items inside a frame using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer and get the properties of each field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Dim frmDOC As DispHTMLDocument = CType(CType(HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(1), SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2).Document, DispHTMLDocument)

dim iHTMLCol as IHTMLElementCollection = frmDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

After this, you can use For Loop for `IHTMLElementCollection` collection.